# PVS-Studio: warning V609 is generated even if denominator is checked

Tags: pvs-studio

```
#define b1 0x01
#define b2 0x02
#define b3 0x04
#define b1 0x08

int flag = get_flag();
int x1 = ((flag & b1) ? 1 : 0) + ((flag & b2) ? 1 : 0);
int x2 = ((flag & b3) ? 1 : 0) + ((flag & b4) ? 1 : 0);
int x = max(x1, x2);
if (x < 1)
    throw "fail";
int y = 1 / x;        // <<< V609: Divide by zero. Denominator range [0..2]
```

`y` will not be evaluated if `x < 1`, but V609 is generated. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the code fragment. This is a false positive indeed. We'll investigate the reasons why it appears and will try to fix this flaw.

As for now, we suggest using one of the means of [false positive suppression](https://www.viva64.com/en/m/0017/) or use [suppression base](https://www.viva64.com/en/m/0032/).